# Generating all possible outcomes in r

Tags: r, combinations

Given a vector with numeric values, how do I generate all possible outcomes for subtraction to find the differences and put them in a data.frame?

```
dataset1 <- data.frame(numbers = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
```

i.e. (1 - 1, 1 - 2 , 1 - 3,...)

Ideally, I would want the output to give me a data frame with 3 columns (Number X, Number Y, Difference) using dataset1.

Answer (score 3):

The `expand.grid` function can get you "pairings" which are  different than the pairings you get with `combn`. Since you included `1-1` I'm assuming you didn't want since it doesn't return `1-1` and only gives you 45 combinations.

```
> pairs=expand.grid(X=1:10, Y=1:10)
> pairs$diff <- with(pairs, X-Y)
> pairs
     X  Y diff
1    1  1    0
2    2  1    1
3    3  1    2
4    4  1    3
5    5  1    4
6    6  1    5
7    7  1    6
8    8  1    7
9    9  1    8
10  10  1    9
11   1  2   -1
12   2  2    0
13   3  2    1
14   4  2    2
15   5  2    3
16   6  2    4
17   7  2    5
snipped remainder (total of 100 rows)
```

Use `outer` as another way to get such a group of paired differences;

```
> tbl <- matrix( outer(X=1:10, Y=1:10, "-"), 10, dimnames=list(X=1:10, Y=1:10))
> tbl
    Y
X    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
  1  0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9
  2  1  0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8
  3  2  1  0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7
  4  3  2  1  0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6
  5  4  3  2  1  0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5
  6  5  4  3  2  1  0 -1 -2 -3 -4
  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0 -1 -2 -3
  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0 -1 -2
  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0 -1
  10 9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
```

But I didn't see a compact way to create a dataframe of the sort you specified.

The now deleted comment by @RitchieSacramento <strike>is</strike>was correct:

```
> tbl <- matrix( outer(X=1:10, Y=1:10, "-"), 10, dimnames=list(X=1:10, Y=1:10))
> as.data.frame.table(tbl)
     X  Y Freq
1    1  1    0
2    2  1    1
3    3  1    2
4    4  1    3
5    5  1    4
6    6  1    5
7    7  1    6
8    8  1    7
9    9  1    8
10  10  1    9
11   1  2   -1
12   2  2    0
13   3  2    1
14   4  2    2
15   5  2    3
16   6  2    4
```

Comment: @RitchieSacramento: I thought so as well but trying just as.data.frame  on the output of outer failed so I gave up. Maybe I should have used the whole method name.

Comment: Sorry, deleted the comment because the `X` and `Y` cols are factors by default so thought it might be a gotcha if one was expecting the original class.

Comment: The only minor infelicity was the labeling of the differences column.

Comment: Use the `responseName` argument.

Comment: Thanks. Apparently I’ve not consulted the Fine Manual recently. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `combn()` function to generate the list of all combinations take 2 at a time.

```
numbers = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
output <-combn(numbers, 2, FUN = NULL, simplify = TRUE )

answer <- as.data.frame(t(output))
answer$Difference <- answer[ ,1] - answer[ ,2]

head(answer)

  V1 V2 Difference
1  1  2         -1
2  1  3         -2
3  1  4         -3
4  1  5         -4
5  1  6         -5
6  1  7         -6
```